# How can we add EOF in file stream in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, eof

I want to read PDF files with Python and pypdf library. Some PDF files have no EOF and the script throws exception.

```
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader(f)
```

How can I add `b'%%EOF'` in **f** IO stream so as to overcome this problem?

Comment: [Use exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Comment: See [How can I fix/repair a corrupted PDF file?](https://superuser.com/q/278562/64857)

Answer (score 0):

Adding %%EOF is not a working solution it is simply a "Tip of the iceberg" indicator of a much greater corruption. A PDF potentially may  have hundreds of %%EOF but the message usually only relates to the true final EOF.

It simply warns the file is corrupt beyond "most" repairs. Whilst attempting repairs is perfectly acceptable the warning / error indicates potentially a totally wrong file type or a small fault and no way to know which.

There are many working PDFs which do NOT have an EOF and adding one could itself corrupt them functioning.

This file ends without an %%EOF (it was modified by an edit, it could simply be poor transmission.) and is a signed file thus adding %%EOF would make matters worse, what is needed is cutting back to the previous valid %%EOF or altering the xref entries.

```
29 0 obj
<<           /Root 2 0 R/Size 30/Prev 11368/Type/XRef/W[1 4 1]/Index[8 1 23 7]/Length 40/Filter/FlateDecode>>
stream
xœcd`ÐÇÀÈÀ '&‚H}a0yDœ‘†Ê ÒÈ† z0
endstream
endobj

xref
```

[image]

If we trim off the corruption after the previous %%EOF we get a valid file.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I don't have a pdf file to test it on, but can't you do something with:

```
try x

if returns exception, break

else, read the current page
```